# Swift - Setting corner radius on image nested in UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a button which contains text and an image but I would like the image to have a corner radius on it. When I try to apply the corner radius to the button, it applies to the whole button which I guess is correct. How can I set the corner radius to the image instead?

Here's my code:

```
let titleButton = UIButton()
titleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
titleButton.setTitle("display name", for: .normal)
titleButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "imgName"), for: .normal)
titleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
titleButton.layer.cornerRadius = titleButton.frame.width / 2

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An `UIButton` has an `UIImageView` on it. So to set corner, simply set radius to the layer of the image view

```
titleButton.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want rounded then set height and width equal

```
titleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

titleButton.layer.cornerRadius = titleButton.frame.size.width / 2.0
titleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

And If you want corner rounded only then

```
titleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

titleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
titleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cornerRadius to be on the button itself and not the image add the following line:

```
titleButton.clipsToBounds = true
```